# user can login from single account detail from multiple locations(computer) at the same time

Tags: plugin-development, users, login

I want user can login to an account from multiple computer at the same time,
i want concurrent login in word-press.
is there any plug-in or custom code for concurrent login ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already possible meaning two people can logon using the same credentials on different computers. No additional plugins or code are required for this.

Comment: Thanks for reply @TomC,
Is there any to  set limit for more then 10 people   can logon using the same credentials on different computers?.

Option for front end user also can check  how many peoples login with same credentials. 

also admin can check from admin site for user profile  with same thing.

Comment: Not as far as I know, but there are other plugins that restrict concurrent logins, so probably not. The following answer from @sisir here may provide some code (in sections 1, 2 & 3) that may help you to check how many are logged in, etc. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181108/allow-up-to-5-concurrent-login-sessions